# SQL - Combining incomplete

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle 10g. I have a table with a number of fields of varying types. The fields contain observations that have been made by made about a particular thing on a particular date by a particular site.

So:

```
ItemID, Date, Observation1, Observation2, Observation3...
```

There are about 40 Observations in each record. The table structure cannot be changed at this point in time.

Unfortunately not all the Observations have been populated (either accidentally or because the site is incapable of making that recording). I need to combine all the records about a particular item into a single record in a query, making it as complete as possible.

A simple way to do this would be something like

```
SELECT
    ItemID,
    MAX(Date),
    MAX(Observation1),
    MAX(Observation2)
    etc.
FROM
    Table
GROUP BY
    ItemID
```

But ideally I would like it to pick the most recent observation available, not the max/min value. I could do this by writing sub queries in the form

```
SELECT
    ItemID,
    ObservationX,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY Date DESC) ROWNUMBER
FROM
    Table
WHERE
    ObservationX IS NOT NULL
```

And joining all the ROWNUMBER 1s together for an ItemID but because of the number of fields this would require 40 subqueries.

My question is whether there's a more concise way of doing this that I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the table and the sample date

```
SQL> create table observation(
  2    item_id number,
  3    dt      date,
  4    val1    number,
  5    val2    number );

Table created.

SQL> insert into observation values( 1, date '2011-12-01', 1, null );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into observation values( 1, date '2011-12-02', null, 2 );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into observation values( 1, date '2011-12-03', 3, null );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into observation values( 2, date '2011-12-01', 4, null );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into observation values( 2, date '2011-12-02', 5, 6 );

1 row created.
```

And then use the `KEEP` clause on the `MAX` aggregate function with an `ORDER BY` that puts the rows with NULL observations at the end.  whatever date you use in the `ORDER BY` needs to be earlier than the earliest real observation in the table.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select item_id,
  2         max(val1) keep( dense_rank last
  3                              order by (case when val1 is not null
  4                                             then dt
  5                                             else date '1900-01-01'
  6                                          end) ) val1,
  7         max(val2) keep( dense_rank last
  8                              order by (case when val2 is not null
  9                                             then dt
 10                                             else date '1900-01-01'
 11                                          end) ) val2
 12    from observation
 13*  group by item_id
SQL> /

   ITEM_ID       VAL1       VAL2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          3          2
         2          5          6
```

I suspect that there is a more elegant solution to ignore the NULL values than adding the `CASE` statement to the `ORDER BY` but the `CASE` gets the job done.

Comment: +1, nice. Could you not just ORDER BY NVL2(val1, dt, date '1900-01-01') for a more compact solution?

Comment: @DCookie - That would be more compact, yeah.  But I always pause when I see `NVL2` because I never remember immediately sure what it does.  I'm hoping that there is something like the `ignore nulls` clause of the `last_value` analytic function  but in an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know about commands in oracle but in sql you could use some how that

first use pivot table is contains consecutives numbers 0,1,2...

i'm not sure but in oracle the function "isnull" is "NVL"

```
  select items.ItemId,
    case p.i = 0 then observation1 else '' end as observation1,
    case p.i = 0 then observation1 else '' end as observation2,
    case p.i = 0 then observation1 else '' end as observation3,
    ...
    case p.i = 39 then observation4 else '' as observation40
  from (
    select items.ItemId
    from table as items
    where items.item = _paramerter_for_retrive_only_one_item /* select one item o more item where you filter items here*/
    group by items.ItemId) itemgroup
    left join 
    (
      select 
       items.ItemId, 
       p.i,
       isnull(    max  (  case p.i = 0 then observation1 else '' end ), '' ) as observation1,
       isnull(    max  (  case p.i = 1 then observation2 else '' end ), '' ) as observation2,
       isnull(    max  (  case p.i = 2 then observation3 else '' end), '' ) as observation3,
       ...
       isnull(    max  (  case p.i = 39 then observation4), '' ) as observation40,
      from 
       (select i from pivot where id < 40 /*you number of columns of observations, that attach one index*/
       )
       as p
       cross join table as items

       lef join table as itemcombinations
       on item.itemid = itemcombinations.itemid

       where items.item = _paramerter_for_retrive_only_one_item /* select one item o more item where you filter items here*/
        and (p.i = 0 and not itemcombinations.observation1 is null) /* column 1 */
        and (p.i = 1 and not itemcombinations.observation2 is null) /* column 2 */
        and (p.i = 2 and not itemcombinations.observation3 is null) /* column 3 */
        .... 
        and (p.i = 39 and not itemcombinations.observation3 is null) /* column 39 */
       group by p.i, items.ItemId
     ) as itemsimplified
     on itemsimplified.ItemId = itemgroup.itemId

  group by itemgroup.itemId
```

About pivot table

create an pivot table, Take a look at that

pivot table schema

name: pivot columns: {i : datatype int}

How populate

```
create foo table

schema foo

name: foo column: value datatype varchar

insert into foo
values('0'),
values('1'),
values('2'),
values('3'),
values('4'),
values('5'),
values('6'),
values('7'),
values('8'),
values('9');

/* insert 100 values */
insert into pivot
select concat(a.value, a.value) /* mysql */
   a.value + a.value /* sql server */
   a.value | a.value /* Oracle im not sure about that sintax */
from foo a, foo b

/* insert 1000 values */
insert into pivot
select concat(a.value, b.value, c.value) /* mysql  */
a.value + b.value + c.value /* sql server */
a.value | b.value | c.value /* Oracle im not sure about that sintax */
from foo a, foo b, foo c
```

the idea about pivot table can consult in "Transact-SQL Cookbook By Jonathan Gennick, Ales Spetic"

I have to admit that the above solution (by Justin Cave) is simpler and easier to understand but this is another good option

at the end like you said you solved